# 802.11N Windows XP Clients Unable to See Each Other

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, 802.11n, windows-networking

I am attempting to update my wireless network from 802.11g to 802.11n.  When connected to the 'G' access point, the client laptops (there are 7 running Windows XP) are able to connect and browse the network for each other.  When I connect them to the 'N' access point they can see the access point, but not the rest of the network.  I tried swapping out the access point with a wireless router, but this did not change anything.

I verified in both the AP and the router that isolation was turned off.  Searching the web has not turned up any other ideas.  The manuals don't show anything either.

Why can't my wireless client nodes see each other on the 'N' network?

Comment: Are the laptops using the same wireless adapters as they were when connecting to the old router? Have you tried running the networking wizards in the Control Panel?

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to determine if any other isolation problem is triggered.
Just ping between your computers. As this is a very basic tool, this should allow you to understand where the problem is.

From computer A: `ping 192.168.0.x` (where 192.168.0.x is the ip address of computer B).
And same thing from computer B to computer A.

Once you have the result of the ping command, paste it here.

edit:
@zippy_raggle Pinging comes back with "Host unreachable"
@Ramhound I suspect your network settings for the two connections are different.

For both computers, paste here the result of the command "ipconfig /all".

Comment: Pinging comes back with "Host unreachable".

Comment: I suspect your network settings for the two connections are different.